# How to create a data summary function?

Tags: r, function, arguments, summary, levels

I'm trying to create a function that summarizes several vectors and the prompt is

```
Write a function data_summary which takes three inputs:\
`dataset`: A data frame\
`vars`: A character vector whose elements are names of columns from dataset which the user wants summaries for\
`group.name`: A length one character vector which gives the name of the column from dataset which contains the factor which will be used as a grouping variable
\`var.names`: A character vector of the same length as vars which gives the names that the user would like used as the entries under “Variable” in the resulting output. This should be set equal to vars by default, so the default behavior is to use the column names from dataset.

The output of the function should be a data frame with the following structure:

Column names of the data frame will be:\
`Variable`\
`Missing`\
The `first` level of the factor group.name\
The `second` level of the factor group.name\
…\
The `kth` level of the factor group.name\
`p-value`
```

I've set up the code already,

```
data_summary <- function(dataset,vars,group.name,var.names) {
}
```

but I'm unsure how to proceed because I do not understand what this is trying to accomplish and what the output should look like. There is an example that shows

```
#data_summary<-function(dataset, vars,group.name, var.name){}

#example
#data_summary(titanic4, c("survived", "female", "age", "sibsp", "parch", "fare", "cabin"), "pclass")
#data_summary(titanic4, c("survived", "female", "age", "sibsp", "parch", "fare", "cabin"), "pclass", c("Survival rate", "% Female", "Age", "# siblings/spouses aboard", "# children/parents aboard", "Fare ($)", "Cabin"))
```

But it really did not help me outside of inputting the arguments for the function.

Comment: This sounds like the assignment is unclear, so I suggest you ask the teacher/professor. That's not to say that we cannot provide assistance given a more-clearly defined problem, but ... it sounds like there is confusion at the source.

Comment: “Write a function data_summary which takes three inputs” … proceeds to list four inputs. Classic!

Comment: I emailed my professor and she said: The fourth input is the same as the second. The input will come in if you want to change your variable name: say you want to change the variable sibsp to “Sibling/Spouse”  then you will need the fourth input otherwise don’t have to use that argument.

Comment: 1st, 2nd, …kth are the levels of the groups. So for example if your grouping variable is ‘pclass’ then you should have mean &sds / proportion (depending whether x is continuous or binary) for all the levels of the grouping variable. In this case it will be 1st class, 2nd class and 3rd class.

Comment: The format_variable_summary function will arrange the data in a format for you for whichever variable you want. It will extract the information form var_summary and arrange it and when you will call it in the summary function, depending on what your variable is it will produce the formatted results for that variable. If you can format the results without using that function please go ahead and do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` package for this function. Also I don't know by which functions you want summarise your dataframe, so I use all functions which `summary` function returns from base package.

My data:

```
> NewSKUMatrix
# A tibble: 268,918 x 4
   LagerID FilialID CSBID Price
     <int>    <int> <int> <dbl>
 1     233     2578  1005  38.3
 2     333     2543    NA  61.0
 3     334     2543    NA  15.0
 4     335     2543    NA  11.0
 5     337     2301    NA  71.0
 6     338     2031    NA  37.0
 7     338     2044    NA  35.0
 8     338     2054    NA  36.0
 9     338     2060    NA  37.0
10     338     2063    NA  36.0
# ... with 268,908 more rows
```

Function:

```r
data_summary <- function(data,
                         variables,
                         values,
                         names = NULL) {
   if (is.null(x = names)) {
      names <- variables
   }
   data %>%
      group_by_at(.vars = variables) %>%
      summarise_at(
         .vars = values,
         .funs = list(
            Min. = min,
            `1st Qu.` = ~ quantile(x = ., probs = 0.25),
            Median = median,
            Mean = mean,
            `3rd Qu.` = ~ quantile(x = ., probs = 0.75),
            Max. = max
         )
      ) %>%
      rename_at(.vars = variables,
                .funs = ~ names)
}
```

Output:

```r
data_summary(NewSKUMatrix,
             c('LagerID'),
             c('Price'),
             c('SKU'))
# A tibble: 32,454 x 7
     SKU  Min. `1st Qu.` Median  Mean `3rd Qu.`  Max.
   <int> <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1    17  39.0      39.0   39.0  39.0      39.0  39.0
 2    18 120.      120.   120.  121.      120.  140. 
 3    21 289.      289.   289.  289.      289.  289. 
 4    24  37.0      37.0   37.0  45.2      45.2  70.0
 5    25  14.0      14.0   14.0  14.0      14.0  14.0
 6    55  30.9      30.9   30.9  30.9      30.9  30.9
 7   117  26.9      26.9   26.9  26.9      26.9  26.9
 8   118  24.8      24.9   24.9  25.1      25.1  25.7
 9   119  24.8      24.8   24.9  25.1      25.3  25.7
10   158 104.      108.   108.  107.      108.  108. 
# ... with 32,444 more rows
```